# How to create a list of joinSteps with jooq

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq

I know that I can add conditions to a list within a loop like this:

```
List<Condition> conditionsList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i= 0; i<count; i++){
    if(x)
      conditionsList.add(mySQLCondition)
}
SelectJoinStep myQuery = dsl.select(…);
conditionQuery = myQuery(conditionsList);
```

Is there a way similar to create an object list of <join.on()> so I can add

```
List<Condition> joinList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i= 0; i<count; i++){
    if(y){
        //In which Objecttype can I store: join(myJoinTable).on(y.eq(…))??
        joinList.add(join(myJoinTable).on(y.eq(…)))
    }
        
}
SelectJoinStep myQueryWithJoins = dsl.select(…).join(joinList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know that [`SelectJoinStep`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectJoinStep.html) and similar API is just convenience for calling `Table.join(...).on(...)`. In other words, you could maintain a local `Table<?>` variable and join additional tables to it as follows:

```
Table<?> table = firstTable();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (y) 
        table = table.join(joinTable(i)).on(joinPredicate(i));
}
```

And then:

```
dsl.select(...).from(table).fetch();
```

Comment: This is it! Now I understand and this solution works. Thank you!